# Kolmogorov-Smirnov and lattice paths

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have seen asserted that the problem of computing the null distribution of Kolmogorov's $D_n^+$ statistic for a finite sample size maps onto the problem of computing the number of lattice paths that stay below the diagonal, and thus can be solved by the [ballot theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). I am familiar with lattice paths and the ballot problem. I am also familiar the expression of the distribution of $D_n^+$ as a series of integrals. But I don't see how one problem maps onto the other. Can someone explain or point me to an ariticle or book that does?

I also see the claim the the null distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov $D_n = \max(D_n^+,D_n^-)$ maps onto another lattice path problem that could be solved by a "two-sided ballot theorem". I don't know what a "two-sided" version of the ballot problem would be. Again, can someone explain or point me to an explanation?

Finally, is there a general framework around all of this? Can the Kuiper statistic be mapped to yet another lattice path problem? The two-sample KS test? The AD statistic?

Comment: I'm not sure about the two-sample problem, but as for references for the former, see:
A. P. Dempster, [Generalized $D_n^+$ Statistics](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177706275), *Ann. Math. Statist.* Volume 30, Number 2 (1959), 593-597. Also, [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/ln8hj5273837522p/), [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/mrx551586853v724/) and [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200514106) might have some material of interest. The first and last links should be to publicly available articles. Sadly, the middle two aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Cardinal 's answers in the comments, I think there is work that addresses the "claim the null distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov maps onto another lattice path problem that could be solved by a "two-sided ballot theorem" and "is there a general framework around all of this? The two-sample KS test?":

[This paper](http://iospress.metapress.com/content/c864m831106611j2/) ([preprint](https://research.wu.ac.at/en/publications/a-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-for-r-samples-12)) is concerned with **r-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov** tests and they derive the exact **null distribution by counting lattice paths** by using a generalization of the classical reflection principle. In Section 2, I find that they lay out nicely how lattice path counting comes into play when deriving the null hypothesis.

In the introduction the paper also features a discussion on how lattice path counting and the reflection principle tie in here by reviewing ideas started with [Kiefer 1959](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-30/issue-2/K-Sample-Analogues-of-the-Kolmogorov-Smirnov-and-Cramer-V/10.1214/aoms/1177706261.full) and [David 1958](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-29/issue-3/A-Three-Sample-Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test/10.1214/aoms/1177706540.full). They also briefly discuss **how it can be seen as an r-ballot counting problem**, referring to [Filaseta 1985](http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=8443337).

They provide a lattice path counting framework for KS type tests for any number of samples. From the paper:

> We consider the problem of testing whether $r ≥ 2$ samples are drawn
> from the same continuous distribution $F(x)$. As a test statistic we
> will use the circular differences  $\delta_r (n) = \max [\delta_{1,2}
> > (n), \delta_{2,3} (n), . . . , \delta_{r−1,r} (n), \delta_{r,1} (n)],$
> where $\delta_{ij} (n) = \sup_x [F_{n,i} (x) − F_{n,j} (x)]$, and
> $F_{n,i} (x), i = 1, 2, . . . , r$ denote the empirical distribution
> functions of these samples. We derive the null distribution of
> $\delta_r(n)$ by considering lattice paths in $r$-dimensional space
> with standard steps in the positive direction, i.e., steps are given
> by the unit vectors $e_i , i = 1, 2, . . . , r$. By a simple
> transformation we show that for some positive integer $k$ the number
> of ways the event $\{n\delta_r (n) < k\}$ can occur is just the number
> of paths $X$ with the property that for each point $X_m$ on the path
> there holds the chain of inequalities $x_{1,m} > x_{2,m} > . . . >
> > x_{r,m} > x_{1,m − rk}$. Indeed, the enumeration of such paths is a
> well studied problem in combinatorics. Again the reflection principle
> comes into play as we have to count paths in alcoves of affine (and
> therefore infinite) Weyl groups; for references on the technical
> background of this topic see [Gessel and Zeilberger 1992](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-115-01/S0002-9939-1992-1092920-8/S0002-9939-1992-1092920-8.pdf),
> [Grabiner 2002](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316501932169) and [Krattenthaler 2007](http://emis.maths.adelaide.edu.au/journals/SLC/wpapers/s52kratt.pdf).

Hopefully this is a good starting point for further investigations into the Kuiper and AD statistics for example.